# How do I write a TAR file to SD card?

Tags: linux, windows, raspberry-pi, tar, sd-card

I need to write the OpenELEC Mediacenter OS image to an SD card for the Raspberry Pi. Usually most OS's provide an IMG file that I can just write with Win32 Disk Imager.

However OpenELEC only provides a TAR file (http://openelec.tv/get-openelec). The TAR file does not contain any sort of disk image. Simply copying the files to the SD card I don't think will work because that won't write to the boot sector etc.

Here's the files in the TAR file:
[image]

How do I correctly install OpenELEC to the SD card/install a TAR file to SD card?

(also the INSTALL file contains a link to their install Wiki which talks about how to install the IMG file which I can't find at all on their Downloads page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image link is below the link for tar file in openelec download page. Just look for "Disk image".

The link is also pasted below for your convenience :)

http://releases.openelec.tv/OpenELEC-RPi.arm-5.0.8.img.gz

This can be written into sd card using instructions from http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/HOW-TO:Installing_OpenELEC/Writing_The_Disk_Image#tab=Windows